# posts_per_page not working in block

Tags: wp-query

I have created a new Block for the Wordpress Editor, and I am trying to get a simple WP_Query to work, but so far, the `$args` in the query are mostly ignored, apart from the `post_type` setting. For example, I want to set `posts_per_page` to 3, but this is ignored. Why is this?

```
<?php
wp_reset_postdata();
wp_reset_query();

$latest_news_args = [
    'post_type'             => 'post',
    'posts_per_page'        => 2,
    'post_status'           => 'publish',
    'nopaging'              => true,
    'ignore_sticky_posts'   => true
];

$latest_news_query = new WP_Query($latest_news_args);

if ($latest_news_query->have_posts()) : while ($latest_news_query->have_posts()) : $latest_news_query->the_post();
    $post_id                = get_the_ID();
    $post_title             = get_the_title();
    $post_url               = get_the_permalink();
    $post_excerpt           = get_the_excerpt();
    $post_image             = get_the_post_thumbnail_url();
    $post_image_id          = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
    $post_image_alt_meta    = get_post_meta ( $post_image_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true );
    $post_image_alt         = $post_image_alt_meta ? esc_html($post_image_alt_meta) : $post_title; // If no alt text specified, fall back to post title
    ?>
    <div class="latest-news-block__post">
        <?php if($post_image): ?>
            <img class="latest-news-block__post-image" src="<?php echo $post_image; ?>" alt="<?php echo $post_image_alt; ?>">
        <?php endif; ?>

        <h3 class="latest-news-block__post-title">
            <a href="<?php echo $post_url; ?>"><?php echo $post_title; ?></a>
        </h3>

        <div class="latest-news-block__post-excerpt">
            <p><?php echo $post_excerpt; ?></p>
            <a href="<?php echo $post_url; ?>" class="latest-news-block__post-more more-link"><?php _e('Read more','site'); ?></a>
        </div>

    </div>
<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: Try `echo $latest_news_query->request;` and see if the query is good. If it's not, it's probably because a plugin, the active theme or another custom code is filtering/altering the query.

Comment: I notice at the top of your file you call `wp_reset_postdata` and `wp_reset_query`, these are unnecessary, and the `wp_reset_query` function should only be used to cleanup a call to `query_posts` ( never use `query_posts` or `wp_reset_query` ). All you need is a single call to `wp_reset_postdata`, it should go just after the post loop  ( `endwhile;` but inside the if statement.

Comment: Also, you mention this is a block, but the code snippet has no block related code, is this a single file or is there surrounding code being ommitted for brevity? Is this a server rendered block? Why was `nopaging` included?

Comment: @TomJNowell To answer your questions about the extra resets and "nopaging" - these were suggestions that I found on other Stack Exchange answers, so basically I've been trying everything, but nothing seems to have worked! 

As for the block itself, I'm using Advanced Custom Fields to create the block, and there is no surrounding code other than the block registration using `acf_register_block_type()`, and that is pretty much a carbon copy from the ACF documentation.

Comment: @SallyCJ From what I can see, it looks good - `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'))  ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 3`

Comment: ah, that complicates things enormously, you're **not** registering a gutenberg block, you're using an ACF API. That's super important to know and could change everything. I'm also deeply suspicious of the `nopaging` parameter, don't add parameters without knowing what they do or why, and remove the othe r`wp_reset_postdata` calls like I mentioned earlier, and eliminate all uses of `wp_reset_query` and `query_posts` from your codebase. Remember, you can ask additional questions to ask what a parameter does, or a function does

Comment: Otherwise, there's an extremely high chance that the answer you seek requires ACF specialist knowledge. What I can see in your code though looks like you could easily do it with a generic Gutenberg block using the standard WP APIs and a server rendered block

Comment: This is what a standard WP_Query post loop looks like: https://gist.github.com/tomjn/3e7e943f91b629325f0ec6a27922d3ca

Comment: @TomJNowell I'm fully aware how a standard WP_Query should look (what you posted is pretty much what I have, but with additional arguments), and I thought I would try `nopaging` given that the documentation implies that it disables pagination. I am not using pagination, so I thought I would try it - no harm in trying things out. Nevertheless, I removed the extra resets, and nopaging - same problem. I even tried the same code in the context of a shortcode and a widget - same problem. The code on it's own on a template works fine.

Comment: @wickywills, sorry, I didn't really notice that `nopaging`, which if you enable it (i.e. disables pagination and the `LIMIT` clause), the `posts_per_page` will be ignored.

Comment: Thanks @SallyCJ - in my case it didn't work before `nopaging` was added, but that's a useful tip to remember!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that there were 'pinned' posts, which were overriding everything. Un-pinning these posts seemed to do the trick.

Also, thanks to Sally CJ for the `nopaging` tip - I wasn't aware that it causes `posts_per_page` to be ignored also.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "is *not*". But let me repost that comment: by "pinned" posts, did you mean [sticky posts](https://wordpress.org/support/article/sticky-posts/)? And the `'ignore_sticky_posts' => true` will by default only take effect on the home page. Secondly, the [`posts_per_page`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/parse_query/#parameters) is used with the `LIMIT` clause (`LIMIT <offset>, <posts_per_page>`), so when pagination is disabled, both the `LIMIT` and `posts_per_page` will (again, by default) not be used. 